# CiviMember permission issue on net new Wordpress install

Tags: wordpress, civimember, permissions

I am working with a test installation of CiviCRM 5.33.0 on Wordpress 5.6 on a local Debian 10 install, MariaDB database.  Vanilla Wordpress, no additional plugins other than CiviCRM.  Configuration checklist is clear, showing no errors.  I have successfully imported 4200 sanitized Contacts with no issues.  Now looking at Memberships.  Membership Dashboard shows a blank page with only the title, nothing else.  New Member gives the "You do not have all the permissions needed for this page" error.  There is exactly one user in Wordpress, my admin user login, and I have explicitly enabled the Member permissions.  I have looked through similar cases listed on StackExchange and while I see things that are similar I do not see any particular "fix".  Can anyone point me in the proper direction?  I see there are two minor updates available for CiviCRM but I don't want to complicate things further by applying them unless so instructed.

All other enabled modules appear to be functional, it is only Memberships that is causing me grief.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It seems I had to add a Price set in Memberships before I could go further.  Doh!  Please excuse my ignorance and ignore the question.

Comment: That's useful information for others Robert!

Comment: I assume this info is in docs somewhere.  I was just bulling ahead without reading.